# Dynamically allocating the memory to WLM queue in redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We have two queues configured in redshift WLM.Memory percentage is 50% for each of them.

1)Queue one is used  for reporting purpose and runs every midnight.
 2)Queue two is used by analyst team to run queries during daytime.

What we are looking for is when queue 2 is idle ,can we dynamically assign more memory to queue1.suppose queue 2 is using only 10% memory can we assign rest of the memory to queue one dynamically.

Comment: Redshift now supports this.if you are interested, Google "dynamic wlm redshift ".

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as part of your code using AWS API or just do your job as administrative user that has no limitation as administrator. Anyway it dynamic resource allocation still not supported.